# Check the correct answer

Tags: android, database

I am developing an app that is a question's game. I managed to show the answers to each question to a different button each time but i am having trouble to check the right answer. My approach is: I created an extra column to the database where i indicate the column where the right answer is(1,2,3 or 4). I use this code for showing the answers in different buttons.

```
cur = dbHelper.getRandomQuestion();
    String corrans = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("CorrectAnswer"));
    a = Integer.parseInt(corrans);
    String question = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("QUESTIONS"));
    String answer0 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("ANSWER1"));
    String answer1 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("ANSWER2"));
    String answer2 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("ANSWER3"));
    String answer3 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("ANSWER4"));
    txtQuest.setText(question);

    ArrayList<String> lstAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    lstAnswers.add(answer0);
    lstAnswers.add(answer1);
    lstAnswers.add(answer2);
    lstAnswers.add(answer3);

     score.setText("Your score is " + b +","+ a);

    Random random = new Random();

    int[] textViews = new int[] { R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4 };
    int textViewIndex = 0;

    while (lstAnswers.size() > 0)   {
    int index = random.nextInt(lstAnswers.size());
    if(a == index){ b = index;}
    else{}
    String randomAnswer = lstAnswers.remove(index);
    ((TextView)findViewById(textViews[textViewIndex])).setText(randomAnswer);
    ++textViewIndex;
                                    }
```

To each button call to compare the values of a and b and then act accordingly. But it doesnt seem to work. I understand why but i cannot figure it out. Any help appeciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Collections.shuffle(list)` to shuffle your answer array and then display the answer 
   Set a tag as "right" to your button where anwer is correct and later compare the the tagvalue and disply right or wrong

EDIT: below thing is just an outline

```
 Here im displaying answers in buttons....

    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3));
        Collections.shuffle(intList);

       Log.d("ERR","List after shuffling: " + intList);  
       // below answers will be assiagned randomly to buttons...
        btn_cmpTagline[intList.get(0)].setText(answr1);
        btn_cmpTagline[intList.get(0)].setTag("right");
        btn_cmpTagline[intList.get(1)].setText(answr2);
        btn_cmpTagline[intList.get(1)].setTag("wrong");
        btn_cmpTagline[intList.get(2)].setText(answr3);
        btn_cmpTagline[intList.get(2)].setTag("wrong");
        btn_cmpTagline[intList.get(3)].setText(answr4);
        btn_cmpTagline[intList.get(3)].setTag("wrong");
```

//On Click

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_tag1:
            Log.d("ERR", v.getTag().toString());
            if(v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("right")){
                //this button has right answer .. do anything 
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btn_tag2:
            Log.d("ERR", v.getTag().toString());
            if(v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("right")){
                //this button has right answer .. do anything 
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btn_tag3:
            Log.d("ERR", v.getTag().toString());
            if(v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("right")){
                //this button has right answer .. do anything 
            }

                    --
                    --
      }
```

Comment: what btn_cmpTagline supposed to be?

Comment: I haven't managed to do much. Getting null pointer exeption. But i am not sure if i do this correclty.

Comment: here i displayed options in buttons...  btn_cmpTagline  are buttons

Comment: glad that it helped.. hapy coding:)

Answer (score 0):

When you remove items from the list the the index of the correct answer will change, so you have to update where the correct answer is located.

Comment: You can get around this by assigning the correct answer to a random slot first, and record its index right away.  Then assign the rest of the answers anywhere else.

Comment: Yes i know, but how to do that when random numbers are produced(between 0-3). How the arraylist is modified with the remove? Lets say that the index=2 and a=1 the size then will 3 but i will not know the exast position of each answer inside the Arrraylist

Comment: Random to decide on what place the correct answer should be. Remove that answer from the list and save it. Use the same loop as you have to go though the rest of the answer with a small modification. When your loop hits the random place where the correct answer should be, insert the correct answer instead of taking a new one from the list.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value of the right answer instead of the index. then, as you add the answers to buttons you can check if it is the same with the correct answer and keep the new index.