# identify correct answer in trivia app

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I'm just about to get into my nitty gritty of my game-changing -_- trivia app but I was wondering before i start my database (SQLite), how would my app know when an answer selected is correct? I was thinking that I could simply put a column in the database for the answer and then have 4 seperate columns for the answers choices, of which one would be repeated -then simply compare the answer selected to the answer of the current row. But this doesn't seem like the most elegant solution. I was simply wondering if there were other methods that I didn't know about.

I don't know if it's worth mentioning but the answers choices would be shuffled before finally being placed into textviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest giving each answer a numeric value (PK from database) and storing the number of the correct answer against the question row in the "questions" table.

As for checking the correct answer, do you really want to be going back to your database for each question? If you app takes off and is used by a lot of people your db is going to be put under a lot of strain. Perhaps have the app download the "round" (set of questions) definition and do the answer checking locally for each round, uploading the results afterwards.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Especially thanks for thinking it will take off, I was being sarcastic. As of now, I wasn't even considering making it an online thing, I simply don't have the no how yet. I want to be comfortable making it work locally. If your method is the only other way then i'd rather do it mine. just cause I really want to be able to shuffle the answer choices.

Comment: You can still shuffle the answers. If you had a "Question" object that had four "Answer" Objects (one with the "IsCorrect" flag set to true). When you come to binding the answers to a button, you can do your "random" to determine which button to use for the question.

Comment: ok. I looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086438/check-the-correct-answer. Is this something like what you had in mind? So the array to be shuffled is multidimenisonal? one spot for answer and one another right or wrong value, or correct index value? I just trying to understand.

Comment: alright it took me a long while but i think i finally understand. in fact this is way better than what i was thinking. i wanted to make the shuffled array the strings. but i should just make the array number values (or anything really) set a task to the assigned **index** not string or number. thank so much, I think i got it. also great advice with w/ local checking and getting round of questions. I will definitely consider it if my skills ever get to be up to par.

Comment: i will when i get a chance to test it out.